# Update UI elements with filter in Angular

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

I have a list with data-ng-repeat, filtering on the elements displayed.

```
<ul>
   <li data-ng-repeat="topic in topics | belongs:projectID">
      <span>{{device.name}}  </span><a data-ng-click="unassignDevice(project, device)">Unassign</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

The filter works fine but when I update a topic with something like

```
topic.projectID = 123;
```

It does not refresh. When I reload everything displays correctly, so the assignment works and the filter works, it is only the UI that is not refreshing. This makes sense as the $scope.topics has not changed, so... how do I do the refresh?

Comment: Can you post the full code written inside the angularjs controller, where you are updating the variable??

Comment: If you're updating this `topic.projectID` "outside" of Angular (the framework doesn't know about the change) you may need to invoke `$scope.$apply()`

Comment: @Tomek Sułkowski Can you please give me an example of the $scope.apply()? I am calling it and it does not seem to do averythnig yet when I reload everything is ok.

Comment: @MikeM it really is all there is to it - calling ` $scope.$apply()` (mind the `$` sign before `apply`, you didn't write it above) from enywhere triggers Angular's _digest loop_ in which the frameworks checks for values' changes. It this doesn't solve your issue, we really need more context - the whole controller's and template's source code would be best.

Answer (score 0):

It may be worth looking at the implementation of data-ng-repeat.  You may be editing a copy of the data set, not the actual data set.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Behind the scenes they may be creating a duplicate of the data set rather than interacting directly with the data set you passed in.